# Name for phasor model of light

Tags: visible-light, quantum-electrodynamics, terminology

I'm looking for the name of the model of light "exploring" every path to a given point, and reaching that point with a probability proportional to the square of the resultant phasor's amplitude. (Yes, that's why I need something more concise.)

I'm thinking that Quantum Electrodynamics is too general, and after some googling, "phasor model" doesn't seem to refer to light specifically.

If you can tell me that I'm wrong, or suggest a better name, it'd be appreciated.

Comment: I'm rolling back because it's kind of counterproductive to put the answer in the question title. (Also I deleted some unnecessary comments)

Comment: I did that because the question title doesn't give a clue to what the question is actually about.

Comment: one would naively hope that language would be a bridge between persons with different backgrounds, however it seems that most of the time, the opposite is true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you are referring is just the Feymann path integral, and you obtain probabilities only after you finished summing all the contributions And then, you square the final result - Finally, you divide the result by a suitable constant that guarantees that the probabilities of all possible outcomes sum exactly 1. This is what is called the normalization factor